# Matlab: How to properly use the Java ImageIO class to get a BufferedIMage

Tags: java, matlab, javax.imageio

I'm trying to do a mock-up in Matlab on some image data in a database.  The image data is from java, output as a base64 encoded byte array.  I'm not familiar with the [java image] format.  However, I wrote the following Matlab code based on some java written by someone working with me.  They follow the same basic outline, and the Java code is able to read the image just fine.  The Matlab code looks like this:

```
function [ result ] = queryDb( theQuery )
  conn   = database( ... ); % connect to the database
  result = fetch( exec( conn, theQuery ) );
  result = result.Data;

  close( conn );
end

data = queryDb( 'sql query to get the data' );
data = uint8( data{1,1} );
data = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64( data );
data = uint8( 127 + data ); % the base64 decoder returns signed int8

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

dataStream    = ByteArrayInputStream( data );
bufferedimage = ImageIO.read( dataStream );
```

Upon inspection of `bufferedimage`, it is an empty array of `double` as opposed to a java `BufferedImage` instance.

I ran a few tests on `dataStream` to see if it behaved as expected; sort of a mini unit test along the lines of:

```
for jj = 1:10
  for kk 1:10
    assert( dataStream.read() == data(kk) );
  end;

  dataStream.reset();
end;
```

It checked out, so this leads me to believe the problem is with ImageIO or my use of it.

Unfortunately, none of the examples I've found for using ImageIO (and some of these other APIs) are used in quite the manner I outline here (in Matlab that is).

[This code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21993-viewer3d/content/ReadData3D/mha/mha_read_volume.m) uses `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream` in the same manner -- in the sense that the provided data is an array of bytes.

[This code](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2WPAYR/?solution=1-2WPAYR) is essentially what I'm looking to do -- convert a java image to a Matlab array.  Unfortunately, they cheat by taking a Matlab image, turning it into a java image, then turn it back.

[This code](http://vision.psych.umn.edu/users/boyaci/Guide_v00/chDemo/demos/HelloPsychophysicist.m) uses ImageIO, but it does so by reading from a file stream.  I tried writing the data out to a file then reading it in using `java.io.File`, but I get the same result either way.

So, I'm at a loss.

Comment: What are the definitions of data, dataStream, and bufferedImage?

Comment: Matlab is not a declarative language.  The way the code is written, combined with my comment(s), will spell out what they represent.  Data is a java image stored as an int8 array.  I'm not familiar with the format.  If you're familiar enough with Java then this may be more apparent.  The problem is the very last line.  Up to the point where dataStream comes into being, everything behaves the same as the java version of this code.  Reading from the stream returns the same data on either side.  ImageIO.read() does not work correctly from Matlab, though, and I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach outlined in the question works ... the only thing I have that differs in any way from the code above is I'm not adding 127 to the uint8 array:

```
% Do all the imports
% sql query to get the data
dataStream    = ByteArrayInputStream( decodeBase64( rows.data{1} ) );
bufferedImage = ImageIO.read( dataStream );
[w h] = deal( theWidth, theHeight );
imageData     = uint8( bufferedImage.getData.getPixels( 0,0,w,h,[] ) );
imageData     = permute( reshape( imageData, [3 w h] ), [2 3 1] );

imshow( imageData );
% voila
```

---

*edit* Incorporating the text @kchja [linked to](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2WPAYR/?solution=1-2WPAYR), in case that link becomes invalid:

> Subject: How can I convert a "Java Image" object into a MATLAB image
>   matrix?
>
> Problem Description: The IM2JAVA function is available for converting
>   a MATLAB image into a Java image. I would like to convert a Java image
>   to a MATLAB image.
>
> Solution: There is no built-in function to convert Java images into
>   MATLAB images. However using the Java API you can extract the data
>   from a Java image and store it as a matrix, which is MATLAB's image
>   representation.
>
> Below is an example of converting a MATLAB image to Java and back to a
>   MATLAB image. The image used in this example is part of the MATLAB
>   demos and is on the MATLAB path. In this example, the "getPixels"
>   function of the Java class "Raster" returns the RGB values for the
>   image.
>
> Depending upon the format of your Java image, additional work may be
>   required. Java images can be stored in one of many formats; the
>   "getPixels" function returns the pixel data in that format. For more
>   information, see the javadoc page for the java.awt.image.Raster class
>   at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html

```
% create java image
I = imread('office_3.jpg');
javaImage = im2java(I);

% get image properties
H=javaImage.getHeight;
W=javaImage.getWidth;

% repackage as a 3D array (MATLAB image format)
B = uint8(zeros([H,W,3]));
pixelsData = uint8(javaImage.getBufferedImage.getData.getPixels(0,0,W,H,[]));
for i = 1 : H
base = (i-1)*W*3+1;
B(i,1:W,:) = deal(reshape(pixelsData(base:(base+3*W-1)),3,W)');
end

% display image
imshow(B);
```

> The following are two other ways to implement this (in a more
>   optimized manner):
>
> Example 1: (Faster execution)

```
pixelsData = reshape(typecast(jImage.getData.getDataStorage, 'uint8'), 4, w, h);
imgData = cat(3, ...
        transpose(reshape(pixelsData(3, :, :), w, h)), ...
        transpose(reshape(pixelsData(2, :, :), w, h)), ...
        transpose(reshape(pixelsData(1, :, :), w, h)));
```

> Example 2:

```
imgData = zeros([H,W,3],'uint8');
pixelsData = reshape(typecast(javaImage.getBufferedImage.getData.getDataStorage,'uint32'),W,H).';
imgData(:,:,3) = bitshift(bitand(pixelsData,256^1-1),-8*0);
imgData(:,:,2) = bitshift(bitand(pixelsData,256^2-1),-8*1);
imgData(:,:,1) = bitshift(bitand(pixelsData,256^3-1),-8*2);
```

Comment: Just for completeness's sake, if somebody is going to solve this problem too, MathWorks gives [another solutions](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2WPAYR/?solution=1-2WPAYR) how to convert BufferedImage to Matlab's uint8 image. It also gives images in correct orientation (when I tested the Brian Vandenberg's code, the images were rotated for 90 degrees).

Comment: ::nod::, I didn't need to worry too much about orientation, so that didn't even occur to me.